# Delete HTML table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table in which rows can be added dynamically by button click(Also done with jQuery). What I want now is,I need to have a button by the side of each row. Pressing it would delete that particular row.

The table is as follows.

```
<tr class="item-row">
         <td class="item-name">
          <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>

           <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>           

          <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
          <td><span class="price"></span></td>
      </tr>
```

The Jquery to add more rows is as follows.

```
 $("#addrow").click(function(){
$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><input type="text" class="slno"/><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td><td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td><td><span class="price"></span></td></tr> ');
```

The function I am using is this. But it's not working.

```
$(".delete").on('click',function(){
$(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
update_total();
if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
  });
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the rows are dynamic you need a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the elements. `document` is the best default if nothing is closer/convenient:

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(){
    $(this).closest('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
});
```

In your example the `table` element would be a good target.

e.g.

```
$('#items').on('click', ".delete", function(){
    $(this).closest('.item-row').remove();
    update_total();
    if ($(".delete").length < 2) $(".delete").hide();
});
```

Delegated events work by applying the jQuery selector at event time, not when the event was registered. This means they can exist later.

Comment: The table ID is "items". Is that what is required?

Answer (score 1):

First, put the table label on the add, then try this :

```
            $('table').on('click', ".delete", function() {
              $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // more simple
            });
```

Comment: You may need to reword "put the table label on the add" as I can't understand what you meant. Also, delegated events should target a single specific element, or `document` as the default. Otherwise you can wind up with multiple delegated handlers, which is wasteful/pointless. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btadd').click(function () {

            szTr='<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td><td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td><td><span class="price"></span></td></tr>';

            $('#tbl_test tbody').append(szTr)
        });

        $('table').on('click', ".delete", function () {
            $(this).closest('tr.item-row').remove();

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button value="Add Row" id="btadd">Add Row</button>
      <table id="tbl_test">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="item-row">
         <td class="item-name">
          <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>

           <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>         

          <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
          <td><span class="price"></span></td>
        </tr>   

               <tr class="item-row">
         <td class="item-name">
          <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>

           <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>           

          <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
          <td><span class="price"></span></td>
        </tr>  
              </tbody>
      </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better - downvote removed. With delegated event handlers, you should either target a single specific element, or `document` as the default. If for example there are multiples tables in a page your example will be attaching multiple delegated handlers when only one is needed.